# manual install perl-5.10.1-3.tar.bz2 on cygwin

Tags: linux, perl, cygwin

I have the binaries: perl-5.10.1-3.tar.bz2 and I don't have access (admin privileges) to run setup.exe for cygwin, my question is how can I install manually inside cygwin the module for perl: perl-5.10.1-3.tar.bz2
?
(or maybe can I get the sources and compile? can someone tell me please how?)
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
bzip2 -d perl*.tar.bz2
tar xf perl*.tar
cd perl*
./Configure
make
```